# How to pass parameters on OBJECT_URL when posting a action on facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I mean in this line:

```
FB.api('/me/namespace:read' + 
'?article=http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tm/redir.php&access_token=','post',
```

If i try:

http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tm/redir.php?id=454545

it returns errors, how can i pass parameters in this OBJECT_URL?

Comment: What is `OBJECT_URL`? Never seen it, and it's not in your code.

Comment: Would help if you shared errors returned as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to urlencode your url.

```
"/me/namespace:read?article=" + 
encodeURIComponent("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/tm/redir.php?id=454545") + 
"&access_token="+access_token
```